# I/O Stream String Manipulation (Correct Cin/cout operators <</>>)

Tags: c++, string, iostream, fstream

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487653/a-program-that-will-correct-a-c-program-that-has-errors-in-the-operator) on here and had a further question about the answer give (I can't comment since I'm new to stackoverflow). The guy who answered it seems to be right about replacing << >> for `cin` and `cout`. But the problem I'm having is that all the semi-colons won't show up in the new output file.

I know that *while `std::getline(input, command, ';')`*  erases all semicolons, but theyre supposed to be put back with the else statement at the end, but it isn't being replaced when I run it. And if I omit ';' out of the `getline` statement everything in the output file messes up.

How do you make it show that the semi-colon does show?

```
void print(ifstream& input,ofstream& output)
{
    bool first = true;
    std::string command;
    while(std::getline(input, command, ';'))
    { // loop until no more input to read or input fails to be read
        if (command.find("cin")!= std::string::npos)
        { // found cin somewhere in command. This is too crude to work. See below
            size_t pos = command.find("<<"); // look for the first <<
            while (pos != std::string::npos)
            { // keep replacing and looking until end of string
                command.replace(pos, 2, ">>"); // replace with >>
                pos = command.find("<<", pos); // look for another 
            }
        }
        else if (command.find("cout")!= std::string::npos)
        { // same as above, but other way around
            size_t pos = command.find(">>"); 
            while (pos != std::string::npos)
            {
                command.replace(pos, 2, "<<");
                pos = command.find(">>", pos);
            }
        }
        if (! first)
        {
            output << command; // write string to output
        }
        else
        {
            first = false;
            output << ';' << command; // write string to output
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `std::getline` function does not alter the contents of the flle.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you are having issues with.

Comment: Apologies. Edited.

Comment: Is this the actual code? The `look_for_arrow1` variable seems to be undeclared.

Comment: edited with the code from the link. its spitting an output file with the correct text and corrected cin/cout operators but without the semicolons. i assume getline is doing this but i thought the else statement at the end is putting it back in.

Comment: Can confirm the problem. I've added a comment on the answer you linked.

Comment: A good example why why one should compile and test answers. I wonder what that idiot was thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        if (! first)
        {
            output << command; // write string to output
        }
        else
        {
            first = false;
            output << ';' << command; // write string to output
        }
```

In the first iteration, the `else` branch gets executed and a semicolon is printed.

In any later iteration, the `if` branch is executed, which does **not** print a semicolon.

The fix is easy: Swap the two lines starting with `output <<`.

Comment: Thanks you. It seems to be working now. However, a semi-colon appears now at the beginning of the txt file I was testing. All the semicolons that were omittted with getline comeback, but a new one appears as the first character in the file.

Comment: Actually fixed it. In the `if(! flag)` statement I just added and `&& !(line.find("#") != string::npos))`